# jquery has() not working

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$("p:has(form)").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="edit">test</p>
<p class="edit">test</p>
<p class="edit">test</p>
<p class="edit">
    <form>test</form>
</p>
<p class="edit">test</p>
<form>test</form>
<form>
    <p>test</p>
</form>
```

This is not working, check if form has p works..

any solutions ?

**Update**
p has to be a span, stupid me, thanks alot

Comment: you can not put form in p element.

Comment: it²s a plugin called: jeditable

Comment: You can't put forms in p elements, no matter what the plugin is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in HTML, paragraphs cannot contain forms. The browser "fixes" your markup by closing the paragraph tag before the form and opening another one after it:

```
<p class="edit">
    </p><form>test</form>
<p></p>
```

This changes your markup and jQuery can not longer match `p:has(form)`. Change your markup, replace P with something else, may be a div.

Comment: i replace p with span and it works, its a plugin that do that little thing (jeditable) thanks :D

Comment: Span is equally bad. Use div.

Comment: Salman.. its okeay, thank you very much i will accept your answer in 5 min ;-)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  $("p").has("form").css("color","red");
```

Comment: This is functionally exactly the same as the code in the question, and it doesn't work for the same reason.